# Hibernate lazy loading and REST API client GET request

Tags: hibernate, rest, lazy-loading, crud

A question about best practice.

There is a REST API service and hibernate is used as a repository. There are entities that have  fields  lazy loading. The REST API client sometimes needs to get an entity without lazy fields, and sometimes  them, while the logic of getting does not change.

In terms of best practices, what is the best way to make an API for choosing to receive related entities?

Thinking of making different endpoints or making parameters  List

Answer (score 0):

Use GraphQL if you have different representation needs. With Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views and the [GraphQL integration](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/entity-view/manual/en_US/#usage-4) this is easy peasy. Checkout the example project and play around with it: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence/tree/main/examples/spring-data-graphql